# Adyen web drop in error with the github project

Tags: c#, asp.net, adyen

I'm trying to implement an end-to-end proof-of-concept to Adyen's Web Drop-In with the .NET project here https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-dotnet-online-payments.

I've pulled the latest stable. I also set the following hard-coded from the values I got off my test Adyen account.

ADYEN_API_KEY
ADYEN_MERCHANT
ADYEN_CLIENT_KEY

When I start the server (dotnet run) and go to https://localhost:5001, Chrome changes it to not secure. I chose Drop-in and after clicking "Continue to Checkout", it fails with the error below:

[image]

Comment: It looks like it fails before loading the drop-in component, possibly the call to the backend to initialise the session. Can you post the logs you get in the application (running locally)? Also the response/errors you see in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Happy to help!

Please go to your ca-test environment.
Under your merchantAccount > Developers (in the left-tab-menu) > API credentials > Find your ws_00000 user. In the "Allowed origins"-section, you can add your allowed origins. In your case, add "https://localhost:5001" and you should be good to go!

Comment: Awesome, this fixed it!